Failed to resolve assembly 'nameofDLL_sdk version 1.7.0.0, culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=null',
When i start project it Will show 5errors in 5 pages app.xaml,appshell.xaml,maipage.xaml,colors.xaml And styles.xaml everytime on first line
Failed to resolve assembly 'nameofDLL_sdk version 1.7.0.0, culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=null',
I tried reinstal, update everything, looked for solutions on internet And Now i am asking you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
